# How to do a DIY LCD output from a busted android tablet?

Tags: arm, android

I have a cheap android tablet with a busted screen.  Replacement screens cost more than a new tablet and I hate to waste it since it's only a few weeks old.  I took it apart and it runs on a [Allwinner A13](http://linux-sunxi.org/images/e/eb/A13_Datasheet.pdf) ARM chip.  The LCD section of the data sheet doesn't seem all that helpful.  Is there any way to get a VGA output from the chip?  I see the chip has LCD pins for vsync and hsync but I'm lost after that.  Is this a reasonable project to take up or should I just throw it out?

Comment: I guess you'd have to (re)write a significant part of the software to get VGA output, and you will very likely need information that is not freely available. In other words: a waste of your time. But did you check wide enough for a replacement? Last year my son dropped his shiny new Galaxy (S3?). I got a replacement LCD/touch for ~ $20 and repaired it.

Comment: Well it was only $35 to begin with.  I looked but it's some obscure brand and probably not worth fixing anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make my comment an answer: I would advise you to throw it out. A $100 phone might have been worth the replacement parts and repair effort, but not a $35 phone.